# Is it possible to specify a Trait for a companion object?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have this:

```
trait FormData

case class DepartmentData(id: Long, title: String) extends FormData
```

and this companion object:

```
object DepartmentData {
  def empty: DepartmentData = ???
  def from(value: SomeKnownType): DepartmentData = ???
}
```

What I would like is to make sure that all the classes implementing the `FormData` Trait, have the two methods `empty` and `from` in their companion object.

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you provide a little more information on _why_ you want this, then someone may be able to provide an alternative solution that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think we can do this directly, however try *type class* solution like so

```
trait FormData
case class DepartmentData(id: Long, title: String) extends FormData
case class EmployeeData(id: Long, title: String) extends FormData

trait SomeKnownType

trait FormDataFactory[T <: FormData] {
  def empty: T
  def from(value: SomeKnownType): T
}

object FormDataFactory {
  def empty[T <: FormData](implicit ev: FormDataFactory[T]): T = ev.empty
  def from[T <: FormData](value: SomeKnownType)(implicit ev: FormDataFactory[T]): T = ev.from(value)

  implicit object fooDepartmentData extends FormDataFactory[DepartmentData] {
    override def empty: DepartmentData = ???
    override def from(value: SomeKnownType): DepartmentData = ???
  }

  implicit object fooEmployeeData extends FormDataFactory[EmployeeData] {
    override def empty: EmployeeData = ???
    override def from(value: SomeKnownType): EmployeeData = ???
  }
}
```

Now call

```
FormDataFactory.empty[DepartmentData]
FormDataFactory.empty[EmployeeData]
```